# Setting my JAVA_HOME variable for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I have tried setting my `JAVA_HOME` variable for Hadoop to no avail.

My Java runtime is in `/usr/bin/java`, but Hadoop keeps trying to access it in `/usr/bin/java/bin/java`.

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` in my `.bash_profile` and in `bin/hadoop`, but neither works. I am guessing that some other path setter is overriding this. Is this a known problem and what can be done about it?

A couple of other things I tried:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME from the hadoop script
add $JAVA_HOME to the conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:
JAVA_HOME = /usr

The code assumes that the executable is located at:
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely your Java *installation* is in `/usr/bin/java`.

The *executable* may be there, or may just be a link to the executable in your installation.

IMO it's cleaner to use your actual Java JDK/JRE directory and use that instead: that's what `JAVA_HOME` is supposed to be.

---

*Using* Hadoop is *quite* a bit more complicated than setting an environment variable correctly; you may be in for a rough road. Consider something like [Kiji's Bento Box](http://www.kiji.org/getstarted/) to ease initial setup.